# Could not find function: resolve-uri

Tags: xslt

When I am trying to transform an XML it gives me an error

> Could not find function: resolve-uri

where `resolve-uri` is an XPath function.

Below is my XSLT line which uses the `resolve-uri` function:

```
<xsl:variable name="filename" select="resolve-uri(concat($dir,'/',$xmlFileName,'_',position(),'.xml'))"  />
```

Can anybody please help me.
Is it because of XSLT version difference?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `resolve-uri()` is an XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) function and won't work with an XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0) implementation.

It depends on your environment if you are able to use an equivalent extension function.

Comment: I am using RAD 7 transformation which support XSLT 1.0 .What i should use instead of that as i am passing value of dir from application.
What should replace resolve-uri ?

Tom,Thanks for reply.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't say what to do for RAD 7. I'm afraid you have to look up how to extend XSLT there yourself, I'm sure you can find something in the docs or on the web.